# Use "[", " ]" symbols in regex in java

Tags: java

I wanted to know how to use "[", "]" symbols in regex, I am getting compile time error. Could anyone help me?

I have to split a string which holds "[", "]" symbols in java, but getting compile time error

```
String strng = "[11 11] 2000";
String ready[] = strng.split("[] ");
```

> Compile time error : Unclosed character class;

Comment: `strng.split("[\\[\\] ]");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex needs to be structured as a character class containing characters `'['`, `']'`, and `' '`. Since character class syntax includes square brackets, the brackets inside the character class need to be escaped with slashes. Finally, since escape sequences are used as part of a Java string, you need to escape each backslash, like this:

```
String ready[] = strng.split("[\\[\\] ]");
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape those characters by using `\[\]` because in regex `[]` are used to create a range.
E.g. `[A-Z]` are all characters from A to Z in uppercase.
Or `[ABC]` is checking if your string contains one of the three characters A, B or C.

So in Java use this code to split your string:

```java
strng.split("\\[\\] ");
```

Comment: @Nodirxon It is very funny to see that you tell dasblinkenlight that his regex works and although oemel09 uses the same, you tell him it now doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Yeap, that's funny, coz you are not looking carefully or couldn't distinguish the difs! There is a difference between "[\\[\\] ]" and "\\[\\] ", "\\[|\\]". The last two didn't work, that's why I didn't mark them as the answer.

Comment: It's working for me. Working means compiling and running without any errors. Tell me which output you expect and I'll correct the regex

Comment: I am getting "[[11 11] 2000]" result if I use "\\\[\\\] ", but getting [, 11, 11, , 2000] as i use "[ \\\[\\\]]".

Comment: the result is a string array

Answer (score 0):

```
String strng = "[11 11] 2000"; 
String ready[] = strng.split("\\[|\\]");
System.out.println("ready = " + ready[1]);
```

> ready = 11 11

```
You need to escape the special characters by escape characters. 
so [ has to be represented as \[ and a ] has to be represented as \].
In Java, you need to add \\ to represent a \.
So effectively \\[ and \\] are used to avoid the special meaning associated with [] and use them as a normal character.
```

Comment: Do not add code only. Write what you have done and why

Comment: Sure.  the idea was to split the string with possible delimiter which are [ and ] so i have tried to show an example around that.